# What is ReflectionClass::IS_IMPLICIT_ABSTRACT used for?

Tags: php, reflection

I'm trying to understand the PHP ReflectionClass but have some trouble. In the documentation 3 modifiers for classes are listed: implicit abstract, explicit abstract and final with constant values 16, 32 and 64 respectively. What I wonder is how the implicit and explicit abstract modifiers work? When is a PHP class implicit abstract?

I tried to figure it out by trial and error with a few simple classes and interfaces and using the ReflectionClass::getModifiers() method to see what happened, however I do not understand the result of the getModifiers method. Using the following interface the result from getModifiers is int(144):

```
interface Animal {
  public function isYellow();
}

$a = new ReflectionClass("Animal");
var_dump($a->getModifiers());
```

With the modifier constants being 16, 32 and 64 respectively I don't get how the method can return 144 at all? Have I misunderstood something about how a bitfield works or why am I getting this result?

UPDATE: 144 as bits are 10010000, so the set bits are 16 and 128. Making interfaces implicit abstract. I would like to know what 128 means though?

I made some testing with classes:

```
class Horse implements Animal {
  public function hasTail() { return true; }
}

abstract class Predator implements Animal {
  public function hasTeeth() { return true; }
}

abstract class Fish implements Animal {
  public function isYellow() { return true; }
}
```

The Horse class throws a fatal error but still defines the class. Reflecting Horse and calling getModifiers results in int(524304), which has the implicit abstract bit set. But what does the other set bit mean?

Reflecting the Predator class and calling getModifiers results in int(524336), which has both the implicit and explicit abstract bits set. The last set bit is the same as for the Horse class.

The Fish class is declared abstract but has no abstract methods. The getModifiers result is then int(524320) which as expected has the explicit abstract bit set but not the implicit abstract bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be additional modifiers used internally that simply don't have a publicly defined constant value, hence the discrepancy in value:

Using

```
if ($a->getModifiers() & ReflectionClass::IS_IMPLICIT_ABSTRACT)
    echo 'IS_IMPLICIT_ABSTRACT',PHP_EOL;
if ($a->getModifiers() & ReflectionClass::IS_EXPLICIT_ABSTRACT)
    echo 'IS_EXPLICIT_ABSTRACT',PHP_EOL;
if ($a->getModifiers() & ReflectionClass::IS_FINAL) 
    echo 'IS_FINAL',PHP_EOL;
```

will identify which of the defined modifiers apply

A look at the reflection source code reveals the following definitions:

```
REGISTER_REFLECTION_CLASS_CONST_LONG(class, "IS_IMPLICIT_ABSTRACT", ZEND_ACC_IMPLICIT_ABSTRACT_CLASS);
REGISTER_REFLECTION_CLASS_CONST_LONG(class, "IS_EXPLICIT_ABSTRACT", ZEND_ACC_EXPLICIT_ABSTRACT_CLASS);
REGISTER_REFLECTION_CLASS_CONST_LONG(class, "IS_FINAL", ZEND_ACC_FINAL_CLASS);
```

so all flags are based on the internally defined ZEND_ACC_* constants, which have a whole range of additional values that may or may not be relevant to reflection but probably still apply to classes

Comment: That actually makes sense, with the internal modifiers, thanks :) I also updated my question with what I found from some more testing of the implicit versus explicit abstract.

Answer (score 0):

The method `getModifiers()` is used to determine the class modifiers defined for a class (or interface or trait).

What it returns is an int, which represent different bits that are set.

For example if bit `public` has value 1 and bit `static` has value 2 then together they'd be `1 | 2` (bitwise OR), which is 3. And you'd get 3 back for a class that is public static. This can be used for both a class and its methods.

Comment: Yeah, that was my understanding of how bit fields work. However the only modifiers defined in the ReflectionClass class are the ones I mentioned in my post. None of which add up to the result 144.